# How do I use recode.h on ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, software-installation, make, c

I'm unable to install fortune package on ubuntu 14.04, got this error.

```
plankinc@singhan-jenkins:~/fortune-mod$ make all
cd fortune && make CC='gcc' \
        CFLAGS='-O2 -DFORTDIR="\"/usr/share/games/fortunes\""    -DOFFDIR="\"/usr/share/games/fortunes/off\"" -DLOCFORTDIR="\"/usr/local/share/games/fortunes\"" -DLOCOFFDIR="\"/usr/local/share/games/fortunes/off\"" -Wall -fomit-frame-pointer -pipe -fsigned-char -DHAVE_REGEX_H -DBSD_REGEX -DHAVE_STDBOOL -I../util'  \
        LDFLAGS='-s' LIBS=' -lrecode'
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/plankinc/fortune-mod/fortune'
gcc -O2 -DFORTDIR="\"/usr/share/games/fortunes\"" -DOFFDIR="\"/usr/share   /games/fortunes/off\"" -DLOCFORTDIR="\"/usr/local/share/games         /fortunes\"" -DLOCOFFDIR="\"/usr/local/share/games/fortunes/off\"" -Wall -fomit-frame- pointer -pipe -fsigned-char -DHAVE_REGEX_H -DBSD_REGEX -DHAVE_STDBOOL -I../util   -c -o fortune.o fortune.c
fortune.c:143:21: fatal error: recode.h: No such file or directory
#include  <recode.h>
                 ^
compilation terminated.
make[1]: *** [fortune.o] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/plankinc/fortune-mod/fortune'
make: *** [fortune-bin] Error 2

fortune.c:143:21: fatal error: recode.h: No such file or directory
#include  <recode.h>
```

This library is used on fortune.c file.

Need help to complete the installation process thank you.

Comment: Any particular reason you are trying to build it from source, when it appears to be available from the `universe` repository? packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/fortune-mod

Comment: I'm learning how to build software for that I'm building it from source. @steeldriver

This is the link which I followed http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Software-Building-HOWTO-11.html

Comment: Well there are a number of packages that provide a file `recode.h` - I *suspect* the one you need is `librecode-dev` - but you should check the prerequisites for the particular software you are trying to build. I also recommend you install and learn to use `apt-file` or the online search tool at packages.ubuntu.com so that you can begin to solve issues like this yourself.